# Need an Example of tf.keras.Sequential() Weight Initialization

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I need to see how I would initialize all layers of a Sequential model with data from a same-sized sequential model.

E.G. How would I initialize the weights for every layer of the following Sequential model?

```
            model = tf.keras.Sequential([Dense(2000, activation='relu', input_shape=(11,)),
            Dense(1, activation='relu'),
            Dropout(0.5),
            Dense(400, activation='relu'),
            Dropout(0.5),
            Dense(150, activation='relu'),
            BatchNormalization(),
            Dense(y_max+1, activation='softmax')
        ])
```

I am fairly new to CNN training and have managed to make the above code work through trial and error and extensive research.

Datatype is list and np.array() of dtype np.float64

The idea is that I grab the weights from one model (same as above) and return it to another model (also same as above). I just need to be able to visualize how I can initialize the weights and biases of all layers using the following:

```
weights = model.get_weights()[0]
biases = model.get_weights()[1]
return weights, biases
```

I have attempted the model.set_weights() method, but I keep getting the following error message, given the code before the TypeError:

```
if iteration == 1:
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.set_weights(None, None)

TypeError: set_weights() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I'd be very appreciative of any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Sequential` example above, each layer parameters can be accessed and assigned new weights as shown below,

```
#example of first layer
model.layers[0] 

#weights of the first layer, 
model.layers[0].weights #gives the weights of kernel and bias of dense in this case

#assign new_weights by
model.layers[0].kernel.assign(tf.Variable(new_kernel_weights)) 
model.layers[0].bias.assign(tf.Variable(new_bias_weights))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the detailed answer. I wasn't finding much of anything specific to bias assignment. I can make the entire example based off your example